# Vue router get value from vue router link

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I have a list here from my table. It has a edit button and if I click edit button, It goes to another component which is called `editTeacher`. My question is how could I get the data from the table and transfer it to my `editTeacher` component. I get the data from route using axios . In laravel it is like this

`<a href="/editTeacher/{{$teacher->id}}" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></a>` .

How could I achieve it in vue?

Here is my code snippet

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-hover">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Birthday</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
   </tr>
   <tr v-for="teacher in teachers" :key="teacher.id">
    <td>{{teacher.id}}</td>
    <td><img style=" border-radius: 50%;" :src="'img/'+teacher.image"  height="42" width="42"/></td>
    <td>{{teacher.firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{teacher.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{teacher.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{teacher.birthday}}</td>
    <td>{{teacher.age}}</td>
    <td>{{teacher.type}}</td>
    <td>{{teacher.department_name}}</td>
    <td v-if="teacher.status == 1"><span  class="label label-success">Active</span></td>
    <td v-else><span  class="label label-danger">Inactive</span></td>
    <td><router-link to="/viewTeacher"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></router-link></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Route

```
//Teachers
Route::get('/getTeachers','TeacherController@index');
Route::post('/addTeacher','TeacherController@store');
Route::put('/editTeacher/{id}','TeacherController@update');
```

app.js route

```
{ path: '/viewTeacher', component: require('./components/editTeacher.vue').default },
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to consider using global state management, using vuex will solve your problems.

Comment: Im new to vue and I want only the simple way to fix this. Sorry sir

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below code for the Vue js edit method.
As per your git repo.

**app.js route**

```
{ path: '/viewTeacher/:id', component: require('./components/editTeacher.vue').default, name: viewTeacher},
```

**Edit Button in Teachers.vue**

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'viewTeacher', params: {id: teacher.id}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Edit</router-link>
```

**EditTeacher.vue component**

```
<template>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="box">
              <div class="box-tools">
                   <img style="border-radius: 50%;" src=""   height="100" width="50">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9">
         <div class="box">
              <form v-on:submit.prevent="saveForm()">
                   <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                             <label class="control-label">Teacher first name</label>
                              <input type="text" v-model="teacher.firstname" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Teacher Last name</label>
                            <input type="text" v-model="teacher.lastname" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                             <button class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                        </div>
                   </div>
              </form>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        let app = this;
        let id = app.$route.params.id;
        app.teacherId = id;
        axios.get('/getTeacher/' + id)
            .then(function (resp) {
                app.teacher = resp.data;
            })
            .catch(function () {
                alert("Could not load teacher")
            });
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            teacherId: null,
            teacher: {
                firstname: '',
                lastname: '',                    
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        saveForm() {
            var app = this;
            var newTeacher = app.teacher;
            axios.patch('/editTeacher/' + app.teacherId, newTeacher )
                .then(function (resp) {
                    app.$router.replace('/');
                })
                .catch(function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                    alert("Could not Update");
                });
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/getTeachers','TeacherController@index');
Route::get('/getTeacher/{id}','TeacherController@show');
Route::post('/addTeacher','TeacherController@store');
Route::put('/editTeacher/{id}','TeacherController@update');
```

**Controller**

```
public function show($id)
{
    return Teacher::findOrFail($id);
}
```

Comment: thanks sir. let me try this. let me ask questions later

Comment: the data is blank sir. but i get the id. How could I fix that?

Comment: my repo is here please help me if you have some time sir https://github.com/vincesanityyy/capstoneproject

Comment: @Vince I have updated answer, Please check. I gave you a basic idea.

Comment: why I got errors sir? Did you test my project repo?

Comment: @Vince I have not enough time to test your repo. But what is error happen?

Comment: `Property or method "teacher" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`

Comment: also this `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fname' of undefined"` and `Cannot read property 'fname' of undefined`

Comment: @Vince Error occurs because your column name 'firstname'  not `fname` OR `lastname` not `lname` . I have update answer.

Comment: same error i got sir. always this `Property or method "teacher" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.` and `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined"`